# Change the dimensions of an array at runtime in java

Tags: java, arrays

For example a 2-D array to a 3-D array.Is it possible using array ? If not, what class should I use to achieve this ?

EDIT : The array dimension is user defined at runtime.

Comment: Could you give some more details?

Comment: provide some more details with tried code .

Comment: The array is declared as a 2-D array and I want to change the array to a 3-D array.

Comment: Can you give example of 2-D array and result 3-D array?

Comment: The array dimension is user-defined.

Comment: So can you give example of user defined array and how result array should look like?

Comment: I dont think you can you this, in 2-d 
array[][] arry
arry[] pointing to another array of specific size. 
thats how 3-4 works. 
you need to create new array and copy content to that

Comment: you its user defined, but once you have created it, than you can make changes, unless reflection has some magical powers to do this.

Comment: Arrays are `Object`s. Therefore you can assign arrays as elements of `Object[][]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change length or dimension of an array, but you can create a new array with different number of dimensions and copy the content of the old array into it.

Small example

```
    int[] initialArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
    System.out.println(initialArray[0] + " " + initialArray[1] + " "+ initialArray[2]);
    int[][] newArray = new int[initialArray.length][3];
    for (int i=0;i<initialArray.length;i++){
        newArray[i][0] = initialArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println(newArray[0][0] + " " + newArray[1][0] + " "+ newArray[2][0]);
```

Comment: What about using another class like ArrayList ?

Comment: The question is what you want to achieve? Is performance important or do you just want to store values?

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
 int[][][] convertinto3d(int[][] d2, int size) {
        int[][][] dimention = new int[size][d2.length][d2[0].length];
        for(int a=0; a< size; a++ ) {
        for(int i=0; i<d2.length; i++ ) {

               dimention[a][i] = d2[i]; 

            }


        }

        return dimention;

    }
```